# Get image list using Orange Cloud API

Tags: api, orange-api

Using the endpoint `/folders` of the [Orange Cloud API](https://www.orangepartner.com/content/api-reference-cloud), I can only get the listing of the files in the main directory:

```
curl -X GET -H "X-Orange-CA-ESID: OFR-2588c...2e64f249ab" -H \
    "Authorization: Bearer OFR-2588c...2e64f249ab" \
     https://api.orange.com/cloud/v1/folders/Lw
```

How could I get photos entries only, including the ones in subdirectories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all photos this way:

```
curl -X GET \ -H  \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer OFR-948ef5..." \
     "https://api.orange.com/cloud/v1/folders?filter=image&flat=true"
```

By the way, the session header is no more necessary

https://developer.orange.com/apis/cloud-france/getting-started#filtering-on-photos,-videos,-audio-files

Comment: Good news for the session header. It will be easier to use. Thanks!

Comment: Do you happen to know if there are any limitations regarding the number of files returned in one API call? I get maximum 550 results, and the pagination is not working for files.

Comment: I'm not aware of such limitaion about the maximum results. Regarding pagination, it includes folders in the result even though the filter option is used